# How to output data in format of JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, ecmascript-6

I try to output the result in format of JSON.
But got error "celsiusObject is not defined".

Part of my code:

```
const select = document.getElementById('select');
    switch (select.value) {
        case 'celsius': 
            value1.value = Math.round(9/5 * (parseInt(currentValue.value)) + 32) + 'F';
            value2.value = Math.round(parseInt(currentValue.value) + 273.15) + 'K';
            json.value = JSON.stringify(celsiusObject);

            const celsiusObject = {
                F: Math.round(9/5 * (parseInt(currentValue.value)) + 32),
                K: Math.round(parseInt(currentValue.value) + 273.15)
            }
    };
```

HTML:

```
<div id="application">
        <input id="currentValue" type="number" placeholder="enter value of temperature">
            <select id="select">
                <option value="celsius">Celsius</option>
                <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
                <option value="kelvin">Kelvin</option>
            </select>
        </br>
        <button id="convert">Convert</button>
        </br>
        <input id="value1" type="text">
        </br>
        <input id="value2" type="text">
        </br>
        <input id="value3" type="text">
    </div>
```

What do I wrong to get JSON?

Comment: You should assign values to variables before using it. In your case when you are using "celsiusObject" it was not defined as it was declared in the next line. Moreover you are using "const" which does not hoist to top. Even if you have used "var" instead of "const" still you would get "undefined" rather than "error". Rule of thumb is - always define your variables at top, so that you need not care about hoisting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting that because you're using the constant before declaring it, instead, your code should look like this:

```
const select = document.getElementById('select');
switch (select.value) {
    case 'celsius': 
        value1.value = Math.round(9/5 * (parseInt(currentValue.value)) + 32) + 'F';
        value2.value = Math.round(parseInt(currentValue.value) + 273.15) + 'K';

        const celsiusObject = {
            F: Math.round(9/5 * (parseInt(currentValue.value)) + 32),
            K: Math.round(parseInt(currentValue.value) + 273.15)
        }

        json.value = JSON.stringify(celsiusObject);

};
```

Comment: why numbers are not in ''''? Like {"F":39,"K":277}, but I need {"F":'39',"K":'277'}

Comment: Because they're float values and not string. If you want them to be added between quotes you can use the toString method, but both are valid actually.

Answer (score -1):

you must define celsiusObject above JSON.stringify(celsiusObject);